# Replace rows based on index with different rows

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list and I want to replace all rows that are given by index pos with rows from different list. But the rows in different list are sequential while the rows in the original list that need to be replaced are not. So I have:

```
pos = {2, 3, 5};
tbl = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 6}, {j, 3}]
newR = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
(tbl[[pos[[#]]]] = newR[[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[pos]];
tbl
```

Is there a better way to achieve that (the 4th line)? I do not like the indexing `tbl[[pos[[#]]]]`, so I was thinking whether it would be better with let's say `tbl[[#]]=...` but then I do not know how to access `newR`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need

```
tbl[[pos]] = newR;
tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your original matrix you might use `ReplacePart`

```
tbl = Round[#, 0.01] & @ RandomReal[1, {6, 3}];
pos = {2, 3, 5};
rep = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

rul = Thread[Rule[pos, rep]]
```

[image]

```
new = ReplacePart[tbl, rul];

{tbl, new} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

For large matrices `ReplacePart` is faster than copying `tbl` to a new matrix and then use `new[[pos]] = rep`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
(*Generate table*)        
table = Table[RandomReal[], {6}, {3}];  

(*Declare positions*)  
pos = {2, 3, 5};


(*Rows to be used in replacement*)  
rows = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

(*Operation*)  
ReplacePart[table, #] &[Table[pos[[i]] -> rows[[i]], {i, Length@pos}]]
```

**Output:**

*Before operation*

> {{0.176331, 0.81517, 0.774912}, {0.525414, 0.837054, 
>     0.0477762}, {0.789959, 0.330025, 0.107919}, {0.259074, 0.148187, 
>     0.462424}, {0.614598, 0.0351278, 0.443029}, {0.319434, 0.714214, 
>     0.636573}}

*After operation*

> {{0.176331, 0.81517, 0.774912}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0.259074, 
>     0.148187, 0.462424}, {1, 1, 1}, {0.319434, 0.714214, 0.636573}}

**Reference:**

[Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)
[ReplacePart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)
[Length](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html?q=Length)
[@ | # | etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)